# Atmostphere and From Menu Photos Tabs In Google Maps

Tags: google-places-api, google-places

I was using Google Maps on my iPhone today and noticed that if you browse the photos there are two tabs at the top called "FROM MENU" and "ATMOSPHERE".  These don't seem to appear on the the desktop version or iOS Google Maps app but only for me on the iOS Chrome browser.

Is there a way to access these lists of photos? I don't see anything in the Places API.  The only way I could replicate this is by using Google Cloud Vision and parsing the tags of the images but it's an expensive service to subscribe to.

Comment: Hey did you make any progress in this? If yes, pls share. Would be very grateful to you. I have started bounty for this as well as I didn't find any solution for this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52711117/how-to-get-data-for-menu-and-product-listings-from-google-places-api

Comment: @NitishNarang there's no endpoints that I know of to do this currently.  The only way to do it would be to grab the Google Places API photos and then use the Google Vision API to analyse the images.