# How to get data for menu and product listings from Google Places API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

On Google Maps, businesses can add product details or food items ("dishes") from a menu to their store or restaurant "place".

How do we get this data? 
In the [Google Place Api, Places details](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details) this information is not specified.

Comment: Really hope this get's answered. I'd love an api that can get menus or store items from google maps. Also, you said you can "add" products to google maps. Is this something business have to do themselves or does google populate this?

Comment: @CTOverton Google says you can use Google My Business Api to Manage your business through the API this includes restaurant menu listings. But its only meant to be used for a single business. You can read more here: https://developers.google.com/my-business/

Comment: Hey, any progress so far in this? Anyone found way to get menu and atmosphere images separately?

Comment: @NitishNarang there's no endpoints that I know of to do this currently.  The only way to do it would be to grab the Google Places API photos and then use the Google Vision API to analyse the images.

Comment: any updates on this?

Comment: There is a recently opened issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/287110100

Comment: any fixes on this yet?

Answer (score 0):

We must set our expectations that Google Maps Platform and the Google Maps Web App are two different platforms, that means both could have different functionalities or results. In this case, the Places API does not return the menu and product listings of a place unlike the Google Maps Web App.

If you want this to be implemented on Google Maps Platform, you can provide an entry for it in the Google Issue Tracker so that you can provide information on it to all Maps APIs users.

To register your interest in this issue, you can file a [feature request](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/support#feature-requests), and star the issue. This will subscribe you to receive technical updates on the issue. Starring the issue also provides Google Maps Platform with valuable feedback on the importance of the issue to their customers, and increases the issue's priority with the product engineering team.